# How to make OCR required when the Opportunity reaches the certain stage?

Tags: opportunitycontactrole

I know there are many solutions for making the Contact Role required on the Opportunity object, but I couldn't find one that could solve my problem.

I need the Contact Role to be required if the opportunity stage is fourth on the list (“Negotiate Contract”) or higher.
Also, I want to prevent deletion of the Contact Role after it’s been selected and the stage is not changed back to the third on the list or lower.

Is there any way this could be done? I have no experience in coding. Till now, I just used apps, triggers, flows and processes which I found on the Internet.

Thanks.

Comment: If you're open to using [DLRS](https://github.com/afawcett/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries), it would be simple enough to roll up the count and just validate that the result field equals zero and join that with your picklist condition.

Comment: I am not familiar with DLRS, but I will look into it. Thanks for the answer, Adrian.

Comment: I tried using DLRS, but I can't finish deploying Apex Trigger and Apex Class. I get the error message: 
"Error:
triggers/dlrs_OpportunityContactRoleTrigger.trigger (Line: 4: Column:9) : SObject type does not allow triggers: OpportunityContactRole"

I am not even sure if I am setting the required fields right...

Comment: That means you can't use the `Real Time` calculation mode. Change it to scheduled. You'll get daily updates. If you want to do better than that, you'll need enough coding experience to write your own trigger. You'd have to teach yourself some Apex, Triggers, and SOQL, at a minimum.

Comment: I read somewhere that I need to use the scheduled calculation mode. Will try with that for now, but I believe I will need Real Time at some point...
Learning coding is something I will definitely need to do.

Comment: Basically this setup would enforce they had to have an OCR by yesterday. I could write up how to do the trigger real time but then you would still have to figure out how to test and maintain. Doesn't really put you in a better position.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this requirement using just your current skill set, you're going to have to live with a compromise. Because of the inability to add an `Apex Trigger` to `OpportunityContactRole`, any rollup calculations will have to be scheduled, meaning they'll run daily.

I'll copy my recommendation from the comments:

> If you're open to using [DLRS](https://github.com/afawcett/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries), it would be simple enough to roll up the count and just validate that the result field equals zero and join that with your picklist condition.

It sounds like you know where to take it from there. That's your best option until you work your way through several Trailhead modules and master the topics of:

- Apex in general
- [Apex Trigger](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/apex_triggers/units/apex_triggers_intro)
- [Unit Tests](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/apex_testing/units/apex_testing_intro)
- [SOQL](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/apex_database/units/apex_database_soql)

Once you master those topics, you will be able to write a validation using `Apex`, specifically the `SObject.addError` method. For what it's worth, your service method to filter records which have an OCR could look something like:

```
public with sharing class OpportunityService
{
    // @param records - pass in trigger.new
    public static List<Opportunity> getRecordsWithOcr(List<Opportunity> records)
    {
        List<Opportunity> recordsWithOcr = new List<Opportunity>();
        Set<Id> opportunityIdsWithOcr = new Map<Id, AggregateResult>([
            SELECT OpportunityId Id FROM OpportunityContactRole
        ]).keySet();
        for (Opportunity record : records)
        {
            if (opportunityIdsWithOcr.contains(record.Id)
            {
                recordsWithOcr.add(record);
            }
        }
        return recordsWithOcr;
    }
}
```

Comment: Once more, thank you for your help Adrian. I will work on the modules and try to solve the problem.

Comment: I'll throw a few more links in there later today.